# Binning data of a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, binning

I am new to python and therefore stuck in a small problem. I have two 3d arrays of 200x200x200 structure. These arrays are related as one has the velocity data and the 2nd shows the particles which have these velocities. Now, what I am trying to do is, I want to bin the velocity array into lets say 50 bins and at the same time find/sum the number of particles which have the velocity corresponding to each bin. So far I have been troubled with developing a logic for this. I tried flattening out the 3d arrays into 1d with .ravel() and then looped over the arrays. However it is very slow.

Thank you in advance and any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to use [`np.histogram`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html), which also returns a count of items within each bin.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.